# UDP communication varies depending on implementation language

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, sockets, networking

## Introduction

I am interested in multiplayer games that communicate via UDP but don't need any port forwarding. So I am trying to achieve this with an own implementation.
I don't need a peer-to-peer network. I just want that single clients can send messages to the server and the server can send something to all the other clients then.

## Server Implementation (Node.js)

The **server** is implemented within Node.js and looks like this:

```js
var socket = require( "dgram" ).createSocket( "udp4" );

socket.on( "message", function ( message, requestInfo ) {

        var response = new Buffer("Welcome " + requestInfo.address + ":" + requestInfo.port);

        socket.send(response,0,response.length,requestInfo.port,requestInfo.address,
            function( error, byteLength ) {
                console.log( "Welcomed " + requestInfo.address + ":" + requestInfo.port );
            }
        );
    }
);

socket.on( "error", function ( error ) {
        socket.close();
    }
);

socket.on( "listening", function () {
        var address = socket.address();
        console.log("Listening on " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    }
);

socket.bind(3000);
```

So the server is listening to the port 3000. I forwarded this port on the rooter which connects the server to the internet. (It is a bit like a rendezvous server when using the UDP hole punching technique)

## Client Implementation (Node.js)

One of the **clients** is implemented within Node.js also and looks like this:

```js
var socket = require( "dgram" ).createSocket( "udp4" );

socket.on( "message", function ( message, requestInfo ) {
        console.log(requestInfo.address + ":" + requestInfo.port + ": " + message);
    }
);

socket.on( "error", function ( error ) {
        socket.close();
    }
);

socket.on( "listening", function () {

        var address = socket.address();

        console.log( "Listening on " + address.address + ":" + address.port );

        var response = new Buffer("Hi Dude! Here is " + address.address + ":" + address.port);

        var host = "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ";
        var port = 3000;

        socket.send(response,0,response.length,port,host,
            function( error, byteLength ) {
                console.log( "Introduced to " + host + ":" + port);
            }
        );
    }
);

socket.bind(3001);
```

When this Node.js script is started a "Welcome" message is sent to the server. The server then answers this message.
All of this is working pretty fine. It also works with 3G connectivity.

## Client Implementation (C#)

Due to I want to use it with Unity3D I need to implement the client in C#. So I used this example from MSDN: [MSDN UDP Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC)

## Problem

Now here is what I can't understand. When I use the Node.js client the server receives a message from the port I defined in Node.js (3001). When I use the C# Client the port seems to be random. This leads to the problem that I never know to which port I have to listen to with the C# client.

So I only see the message coming from the server with the Node.js client but not with the C# client.

I also read that the port numbers are not the same in the private network and in the public network. With the Node.js client it seems like they are.

## Question

So did I understand something wrong with that whole UDP communication thing or did I just implement something wrong?

Comment: The UdpClient constructor has an overload that takes a port no. Have you tried setting that?

Comment: It might be beneficial to also post your C# example code.

Comment: @Praveen Paulose Thanks! Your comment really helped me a lot. I was even using the constructor in the Receiver Thread already. But I didn't choose a port in the other Thread. I fixed this by using only one UdpClient object with the port 3001.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum You can find the C# code example under the link named "MSDN UDP Documentation"

Comment: @Praveen Paulose I marked it as answer! Thank you very much once more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UdpClient has a constructor overload that takes a port. You can use this overload to specify the port no.

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(3001);
```

Leaving the constructor blank or setting it to 0 makes the UdpClient select a random available port number.